# Why is "Studying British girls is smart" an incorrect way to express "British girls who study are smart"?

Tags: sentence-construction

My classmate argues that

> Studying British girls is smart

is grammatically correct because

> [Eating] {apples} is [healthy]

is correct. They are using "Studying British girls is smart" to mean "British girls who study are smart".

Comment: It's grammatically correct ([Ving] [NP] is [Adjective].). Whether 'girls' is a fit direct object for 'study' is perhaps questionable, though only on the level of pragmatics / propriety. 'Smart' here could be replaced by 'a smart [/cool?] thing to do'.

Comment: If it meant 'British girls who study are smart', then 'Eating apples is healthy' would mean 'Apples which eat are healthy' - which obviously it doesn't!

Comment: @Kate 'Eating apples are healthy' is grammatical and doubtless true.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I meant that if the sentence was parsed in the same way that Maria's classmate is trying to parse 'Studying British girls is smart', it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Kate Just highlighting the complexities of the English language. Flying planes can be // is/are dangerous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Aren't you referring to the fact that, mathematically  or strictly speaking, statements can be vacuously true, and that Eating apples are healthy' is an instance of one?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth just as other phrase, but true or not, that's area of semantics. I daresay, studying British girls is creepy (as perceived by those girls), because study also got meaning observe E.g. garden-path "He didn't run because he was afraid" can be true in any way it could be read, with comma or not, but it's not a problem for grammar to solve. We should know what speaker meant to decide if we need comma

Comment: *Studying British girls is smart. Bullying them is not*. How about them apples? However, studying them (one imagines the idea of watching how they behave) does not mean that British girls who study are smart. [to study someone means to observe them, in fact.]

Comment: @LPH 'Eating apple/s' is a compound noun; contrast 'cooking apples'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see, 'apples that can be eaten' then, not 'apples that feed themselves'…

Answer (score 3):

> My classmate argues that "Studying British girls is smart" is grammatically correct because "[Eating] {apples} is [healthy]" is correct.

Yes, the two sentences have the same construction: Subject, verb, adjective. In both sentences the subject is a noun phrase consisting of a gerund (the true subject) and an object of that gerund. Both sentences are grammatically correct.

> They are using "Studying British girls is smart" to mean "British girls who study are smart".

And here they are no longer correct. We can compare "Studying" to "Eating" and "British girls" to "apples." The sentence is saying that **It is smart** (as generality) **to study British girls**, that is, to look at British girls and catalogue their hair color and accent and education level and everything else one does when "studying" something. This may be seen better if we flip the two sentences around:

> - Eating apples is healthy.
>   It is healthy to eat apples.
> - Studying British girls is smart.
>   It is smart to study British girls.

---

To make the sentence mean what your classmate thinks it should, we can change just one word:

> Studying British girls **are** smart.

The rest of the words in the sentence are still *spelled* the same, but by changing the verb **is** to **are** we have completely changed the function of the other words in the sentence. Now the subject, "British girls," is modified by an adjective, the gerund "Studying." *Now* the sentence means "British girls who are studying are smart."

Answer (score 0):

The person in question is confused by homomorphism in the English language. There is a possibility of ambigous reading even if coordination is done right. Such ambigous cases, e.g. [garden-path sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence), may be considered stylistically bad if they weren't meant as a joke. In this case coordination is wrong, so his phrase got wrong meaning.

In the declarative sentence "[Eating] {apples} is [healthy]" the gerund phrase "eating apples" serves as subject.

The verb "is" is predicate here and can be used only with singular subject.It removes any doubt how coordination is happening here.

If that person wants to coordinate predicate with "girls" as a subject of declaration, he must use verb in its plural form,"are". In that case, girls will be the subject and "studying British" - a sequence of adjectives. In his/her version "Studying British girls" is phrase serving as subject, where girls are object.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you get all this grammatical terminology wrong…

Comment: @LPH It could be, because our teachers were trying to use terms from their native grammar which is incompatible with English. I'd appreciate pointers.

Comment: "Apples" is not an appositive in the infinitival clause "eating apples", but instead, an object. "Is" is not an auxiliary but a full verb here. "To coordinate" is not a grammatical term. Also, 'to flip things around" has no precise meaning in this grammatical context.

Comment: /Eating apples/ is/ smart. /Eating apples/ is a gerund phrase that behaves as the subject of the sentence. [...]you **got** this wrong.

Comment: @Lambie let's say teachers were wrong in terminology (parsing their way it cannot be be a phrase, but result of parsing semantically same). Thanks for correction

Comment: [*the* person in question//in *the* declarative sentence//of *an* ambiguous reading//even if *the coordination* // and several other missing determiners.] You have no idea how painful it is for a native speaker of English to read an entire answer without determiners.

Comment: @Lambie same as without proper punctution , I suppose We have edit function though. It's hard to to see text on phone and autosuggestion edits it. I'm tired to re-install the and replace if with of (every time I type of in middle of phrase it replaces with if) but developers of auto-corrector think differently.

Comment: So, turn off auto-correction **or** answer these questions from a computer. :)

Comment: @Lambie that particular one got about 4 year old set of bug report for them to make it a) option b) fix damn logic c) make keystroke correction optional (no, you didn't want to press that key, you meant this key, because you're not English). Their answer is "will not complete", because extra code paths.